# SPARQL: Provide alternate paths with differing lengths

Tags: sparql, rdf, dbpedia

I'm trying to link some local data up with DBpedia to extract information about countries' economic stats. How can I compensate for alternate paths with differing lengths? The field itself is `OPTIONAL` so that the query doesn't miss a result if it happens to not have language listed, but I am getting blank `language` columns on resources that *do* have languages listed.

For instance, http://dbpedia.org/page/Netherlands, http://dbpedia.org/page/Ireland, and http://dbpedia.org/page/Italy index the languages spoken very differently, from a string to different predicates referencing a resource:

Netherlands:

[image: Netherlands Language Screenshot]

Ireland:

[image: Ireland Language Screenshot]

Italy:

[image: Italy Language Screenshot]

Here's a (stripped-down) example query that *kind of* works, but is not great:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
?countryName
?dbEntry
(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?dbLanguage; separator=", ") AS ?languages)

WHERE
{
    ?dbEntry a dbo:Place ;
        rdfs:label | dbo:longName ?countryName .


    # For some reason, stacking two OPTIONALs and BINDing is all that seems to work here, and still not 100%
    OPTIONAL {
        ?dbEntry dbo:language / foaf:name ?dbofLanguage .
        BIND(?dbofLanguage AS ?dbLanguage) .
    }

    OPTIONAL {
        ?dbEntry dbp:languages ?dbpLanguage .
        BIND(?dbpLanguage AS ?dbLanguage) .
    }
    FILTER (STR(?countryName) IN ("Netherlands", "Italy", "Ireland")) .
}
GROUP BY ?countryName ?dbEntry
LIMIT 3
```

[DBpedia Link](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT+DISTINCT%0D%0A%3FcountryName%0D%0A%3FdbEntry%0D%0A%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT+%3FdbLanguage%3B+separator%3D%22%2C+%22%29+AS+%3Flanguages%29%0D%0A%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++++%3FdbEntry+a+dbo%3APlace+%3B%0D%0A++++++++rdfs%3Alabel+%7C+dbo%3AlongName+%3FcountryName+.%0D%0A++++++%0D%0A%0D%0A++++%23+For+some+reason%2C+stacking+two+OPTIONALs+and+BINDing+is+all+that+seems+to+work+here%2C+and+still+not+100%25%0D%0A++++OPTIONAL+%7B%0D%0A++++++++%3FdbEntry+dbo%3Alanguage+%2F+foaf%3Aname+%3FdbofLanguage+.%0D%0A++++++++BIND%28%3FdbofLanguage+AS+%3FdbLanguage%29+.%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A++++OPTIONAL+%7B%0D%0A++++++++%3FdbEntry+dbp%3Alanguages+%3FdbpLanguage+.%0D%0A++++++++BIND%28%3FdbpLanguage+AS+%3FdbLanguage%29+.%0D%0A++++%7D%0D%0A++++FILTER+%28STR%28%3FcountryName%29+IN+%28%22Netherlands%22%2C+%22Italy%22%2C+%22Ireland%22%29%29+.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AGROUP+BY+%3FcountryName+%3FdbEntry%0D%0ALIMIT+3&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=+Run+Query+)

You'll see the results come back formatted entirely differently:

[image: DBpedia result screenshot]

I'd like to write something like

```
OPTIONAL {
    ?dbEntry (dbo:language / foaf:name) | (dbp:languages / rdfs:label) | dbp:languages ?language
}
```

but I'm thinking SPARQL doesn't support anything that complex yet? (I get zero results)

Comment: your property path works, it's just the anytime feature of Virtuoso which returns what it could compute in the given time. You should use a better filter for debugging, i.e. use `VALUES ?dbEntry {dbr:Netherlands dbr:Italy dbr:Ireland}` instead of your `FILTER` which is too expensive. You should also restrict your `?countryName` to English language only, otherwise you'll get the multiple rows for each language of the country label.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT
?countryName
?dbEntry
(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ?language; separator=", ") AS ?languages)

WHERE
{
VALUES ?dbEntry {dbr:Netherlands dbr:Italy dbr:Ireland}
    ?dbEntry a dbo:Place ;
        rdfs:label | dbo:longName ?countryName . filter(lang(?countryName) = 'en')


    # For some reason, stacking two OPTIONALs and BINDing is all that seems to work here, and still not 100%
    OPTIONAL {
        ?dbEntry (dbo:language / foaf:name) | (dbp:languages / rdfs:label) | dbp:languages ?language
    }

   
}
GROUP BY ?countryName ?dbEntry
LIMIT 10`

Comment: you'll still have two rows for Italy here because of multiple English names for it. I'd just group by the URI and use `group_concat` on the names or use `sample` to get just a single name.

Comment: @AKSW ah, I have heard of that. I would use `VALUES` but this is actually just an abbreviated query - I am using this in a `SERVICE` block to match up with my own data. If I try to just match the `?countryName` variable in *both* my local and DBpedia's `WHERE` clauses, it never matches - I think it's a language thing. Can I specify `@en` on my own data in the query?

Comment: you could directly use it on literals e.g. `"Italy"@en` - but then just use `FILTER (?countryName) IN ( ...)` , so no `STR` function necessary anymore

Comment: but it has to be put inside the SERVICE clause, otherwise the whole graph pattern will be evaluated on just returns what it matches in the given time and also - on DBpedia - with a max. number of rows per request

Comment: Can I use it with locally-queried data? like `SELECT ?countryName WHERE { ?country rdfs:label ?countryName . SERVICE <dbpedia> { ?dbEntry rdfs:label ?countryName } }` ? I don't know how to cast local data to `@en`, since the source did not contain that information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited to correct query, having realized your issue...

```
SELECT DISTINCT                                                           ?countryName
                                                                          ?dbEntry
                ( GROUP_CONCAT ( DISTINCT ?language ; separator=", " ) AS ?languages )
WHERE
  {
        ?dbEntry a                                                              dbo:Place ;
                 rdfs:label | dbo:longName                                      ?countryName .
    OPTIONAL
      {
        ?dbEntry ( dbo:language / foaf:name ) | ( dbp:languages / rdfs:label ) | ( dbp:languages ) ?language
        FILTER isLiteral ( ?language )
      }
    FILTER ( STR ( ?countryName ) IN ( "Netherlands" , "Italy" , "Ireland" ) ) .
  }
GROUP BY ?countryName ?dbEntry
```

- [New query entry form](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FcountryName%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FdbEntry%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%20GROUP_CONCAT%20%28%20DISTINCT%20%3Flanguage%20%3B%20separator%3D%22%2C%20%22%20%29%20AS%20%3Flanguages%20%29%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FdbEntry%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3APlace%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%7C%20dbo%3AlongName%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FcountryName%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FdbEntry%20%28%20dbo%3Alanguage%20%2F%20foaf%3Aname%20%29%20%7C%20%28%20dbp%3Alanguages%20%2F%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%29%20%7C%20%28%20dbp%3Alanguages%20%29%20%3Flanguage%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20isLiteral%20%28%20%3Flanguage%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20STR%20%28%20%3FcountryName%20%29%20IN%20%28%20%22Netherlands%22%20%2C%20%22Italy%22%20%2C%20%22Ireland%22%20%29%20%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3FcountryName%20%3FdbEntry%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20)
- [New live results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FcountryName%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FdbEntry%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%20GROUP_CONCAT%20%28%20DISTINCT%20%3Flanguage%20%3B%20separator%3D%22%2C%20%22%20%29%20AS%20%3Flanguages%20%29%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FdbEntry%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3APlace%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%7C%20dbo%3AlongName%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FcountryName%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FdbEntry%20%28%20dbo%3Alanguage%20%2F%20foaf%3Aname%20%29%20%7C%20%28%20dbp%3Alanguages%20%2F%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%29%20%7C%20%28%20dbp%3Alanguages%20%29%20%3Flanguage%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20isLiteral%20%28%20%3Flanguage%20%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20STR%20%28%20%3FcountryName%20%29%20IN%20%28%20%22Netherlands%22%20%2C%20%22Italy%22%20%2C%20%22Ireland%22%20%29%20%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3FcountryName%20%3FdbEntry%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20)

Note -- these properties (and thus your query) will change drastically in the next version of DBpedia. Check out the [current DBpedia Live page on Ireland](http://live.dbpedia.org/page/Ireland), for example.

---

<strike>This appears to do what you want, with just a little bit more [Property Path](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypaths) (the `?` operator on `rdfs:label` following `dbp:languages`)--</strike>

```
SELECT DISTINCT                                                           ?countryName
                                                                          ?dbEntry
                ( GROUP_CONCAT ( DISTINCT ?language ; separator=", " ) AS ?languages )
WHERE
  {
        ?dbEntry a                                                              dbo:Place ;
                 rdfs:label | dbo:longName                                      ?countryName .
    OPTIONAL
      {
        ?dbEntry ( dbo:language / foaf:name ) | ( dbp:languages / rdfs:label? ) ?language
      }
    FILTER ( STR ( ?countryName ) IN ( "Netherlands" , "Italy" , "Ireland" ) ) .
  }
GROUP BY ?countryName ?dbEntry
```

- [query entry form](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&qtxt=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FcountryName%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FdbEntry%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%20GROUP_CONCAT%20%28%20DISTINCT%20%3Flanguage%20%3B%20separator%3D%22%2C%20%22%20%29%20AS%20%3Flanguages%20%29%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FdbEntry%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3APlace%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%7C%20dbo%3AlongName%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FcountryName%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FdbEntry%20%28%20dbo%3Alanguage%20%2F%20foaf%3Aname%20%29%20%7C%20%28%20dbp%3Alanguages%20%2F%20rdfs%3Alabel%3F%20%29%20%3Flanguage%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20STR%20%28%20%3FcountryName%20%29%20IN%20%28%20%22Netherlands%22%20%2C%20%22Italy%22%20%2C%20%22Ireland%22%20%29%20%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3FcountryName%20%3FdbEntry%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20)
- [live results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FcountryName%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FdbEntry%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%28%20GROUP_CONCAT%20%28%20DISTINCT%20%3Flanguage%20%3B%20separator%3D%22%2C%20%22%20%29%20AS%20%3Flanguages%20%29%0D%0AWHERE%0D%0A%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FdbEntry%20a%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dbo%3APlace%20%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%7C%20dbo%3AlongName%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FcountryName%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3FdbEntry%20%28%20dbo%3Alanguage%20%2F%20foaf%3Aname%20%29%20%7C%20%28%20dbp%3Alanguages%20%2F%20rdfs%3Alabel%3F%20%29%20%3Flanguage%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28%20STR%20%28%20%3FcountryName%20%29%20IN%20%28%20%22Netherlands%22%20%2C%20%22Italy%22%20%2C%20%22Ireland%22%20%29%20%29%20.%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3FcountryName%20%3FdbEntry%0D%0A&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on&run=%20Run%20Query%20)

Comment: Oh gosh, I didn't even realize DBpedia was going through an update! I've only been working with SPARQL for ~2-3 weeks now haha. Your queries definitely worked! I think that in combination with @AKSW's note on Virtuoso's anytime feature explains a lot.

Comment: @JoshToth current DBpedia dataset loaded at dbpedia.org/sparql is a dump from Oct. 2016 I guess. (I mean, president of USA is still Obama, no films after 2016) ... Since then nobody ever loaded a new dump, this will happen in near future though. That said, the DBpedia Live endpoint is always (almost) in sync with the data of Wikipedia.

Comment: @AKSW I did see the Obama thing in one of my queries... that makes sense, hah.